# about meaning of "for"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

> While mass inoculation has done far more good than harm, there are instances of vaccines for diseases such as polio and swine flu being rushed out, only ***for*** pernicious side effects to emerge later.

Here I find it difficult to understand what the second "for" refers to. Does it mean in exchange for something? The rush to develop these vaccines  brought pernicious side effects to emerge later?

Comment: Consider *I don't want to give money to beggars **only for** them to buy drugs*. Then compare that to *We don't want to rush out untested vaccines **only for** them to have unacceptable side-effects* (or ***only to find they have** unacceptable side-effects*. Does that make it any easier for you? In some contexts like this, ***for*** means ***for the purpose of...***, but sometimes there's no element of "intentionality", and it just means ***with the result that...***

Comment: It's used pretty much in the same sense as the first "for". In other words, rushing out vaccines for polio and swine flu aids the emergence of side effects.

Comment: Your answer is very clear. So "only for" can be used for a unexpected result. I'll remember this.

Comment: There is no "only for" here. "for" here means **against**. https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk01zvCrx0nmI9U5mcRkbI2vl4zfPHw%3A1598535668317&ei=9LdHX-boEqu5ggfH9pbQAg&q=%22vaccines+against+diseases%22&oq=%22vaccines+against+diseases%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnOgYIABAHEB46BggAEAgQHlDonwRYwLUEYI24BGgDcAB4AIABZIgBxQOSAQM1LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjmsq61wbvrAhWrnOAKHUe7BSoQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Answer (score 2):

> *I don't want to give money to beggars **only for** them to buy drugs.*
> where
> ***only for** X to happen* = ***if the outcome is** [only] that X happens*

> *We don't want to rush out untested vaccines **only for** them to have unacceptable side-effects*
> (or ***only to find that** they have unacceptable side-effects*).

In many contexts, ***for*** means ***for the purpose of...,*** but sometimes it just means ***with the result that...***, with no element of "intentionality". But ***only for*** is a particularly common construction where the ***unintended, unforeseen*** outcome is also ***undesirable***.